# I'm trying to update the scene in tkinter, how can I do it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have an initial scene in tkinter, I want to update it when a button is clicked. But I don't know how to do it. I've tried several stuff but they don't work. What would you prefer?

Here's my Frame:

```
class App(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.screenState = "main" # is either hashtag selection, main, in progress(for hashtag mode), open(for free mode(since we'll need to close it manually))
        self.accountName = ""
        self.accountPassword = ""
```

Code of the initial scene:

```
def GUIMainScreen(self):
        # Create input elements where you'll retrieve the username and the password
        # Username input
        Label1 = tk.Label(self.master, text="USERNAME:", bg="gray")
        Label1.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.15,anchor="center")

        usernameEntry = tk.Entry(self.master, width=30)
        usernameEntry.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.20, anchor="center")
        
        # Passoword input
        Label2 = tk.Label(self.master, text="PASSWORD:", bg="gray")
        Label2.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.27,anchor="center")

        passwordEntry = tk.Entry(self.master, width=30)
        passwordEntry.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.32, anchor="center")

        # Buttons
        # Subscribe & Like posts by hashtag(s)
        hashtagB = tk.Button(self.master, text="Automation by Hashtags", bg="blue", width=20, command=lambda: self.switchScreenState("hashtag",usernameEntry.get(),passwordEntry.get()))
        hashtagB.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.40, anchor="center")

        # Unfollow people that don't follow you
        unfollow = tk.Button(self.master, text="Clear Following", bg="blue", width=20)
        unfollow.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.50, anchor="center")

        # Develop account in free mode
        free = tk.Button(self.master, text="Free Mode", bg="blue", width=20)
        free.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.60, anchor="center")
```

Here's where I want to change the scene:

```
hashtagB = tk.Button(self.master, text="Automation by Hashtags", bg="blue", width=20, command=lambda: self.switchScreenState("hashtag",usernameEntry.get(),passwordEntry.get()))
```

This is the function that is called:

```
def switchScreenState(self, newState,username:str,password:str):
        self.screenState = newState
        if username != "" and password != "":
            self.accountName = username
            self.accountPassword = password
```

The second scene:

```
def hashtagSelectionScreen(self, username,password):
        currentBot = Account(username,password)
        # Passoword input
        LabelHash = tk.Label(self.master, text="HASHTAGS:", bg="gray")
        LabelHash.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.35,anchor="center")

        hashEntry = tk.Entry(self.master, width=30)
        hashEntry.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.40, anchor="center")

        startButton = tk.Button(self.master, text="GO!", bg="blue", width=20)
        startButton.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.55, anchor="center")
```

Here's how I present the scene:

```
def presentCurrentScene(self):
        if self.screenState == "main":
            print(app.accountName)
            self.GUIMainScreen()
            self.update()
        elif self.screenState == "hashtag":
            self.hashtagSelectionScreen(self.accountName,self.accountPassword)
            self.update()
        elif self.screenState == "open":
            # This is for the free mode, since you'll have to stop it manually
            pass
        else:
            # In progress screen for account developing with hashtags, just as same as "open" but you won't have to stop it manually
            pass
```

Here's the main loop of the window:

```
mainWindow = tk.Tk()
mainWindow.title("Instagram Bot")
mainWindow.geometry("1080x900")
mainWindow.configure(bg="gray")
app = App(mainWindow)
app.presentCurrentScene()
mainWindow.mainloop()
```

I think the reason why this doesn't work is because mainWindow.mainloop() will never get to detect the change that happens, and the if presentCurrentScene() only runs once, but I just don't know what to do to meet the functionality that I'm looking for.

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: could You provide [mre]. basically code that just changes scenes (so remove those passwords and all that is not necessary to change scenes (which I assume You meant either Frames or Windows) and while doing this You may come accross the solution)

Comment: and btw `switchScreenState()` does almost nothing, it just changes some attributes, but You should call something to appear for example another scene should be called there

Comment: You may need to call `self.presentCurrentScene()` inside `swtichScreenState()`.  But you need to clear current scene first.  Also `self.master` is used as the parent of all widgets in a scene.  I think it should be `self` instead.